# How to import global variable from another file?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 `.py`s as below. What I want to do is, when I call `dictionary()` function, it will fill the "global" dictionary `my_dict` in my test and when I `print(keys_list)` I want to see the dictionary as a list. If I do it like that, I get  `NameError: global name 'keys_list' is not defined`.

1. `functions.py`

   ```
   def dictionary():
       global my_dict
       global keys_list
       my_dict = {}
       for i in range(3):
           my_dict.__setitem__(str(i),i)
       keys_list = list(keys)
   ```
2. `test1.py`

   ```
   from functions import dictionary

   my_dict()
   print(keys_list)
   print(keys)
   ```

If I define my function in a class as shown below, I get `ImportError: cannot import name dictionary`.

```
class functions:
   def dictionary(self):
       global my_dict
       global keys_list
       my_dict = {}
       for i in range(3):
           my_dict.__setitem__(str(i),i)
       keys_list = list(keys)
```

P.S. The tool is using Python 2.7 (I am trying to write a script for that tool).

Comment: your variables/functions/classes are very badly named.

Comment: "If i define my function in a class;i get "ImportError: cannot import name dictionary" Of course, what did you expect? I'm very confused. Do you think Python looks for arbitrarily deeply nested attributes of objects when trying to import something?

Comment: Also what is `my_dict()` supposed to do? Did you mean `dictionary()` in this line?

Comment: In addition, why do you not get a NameError when you do `keys_list = list(keys)`? Because you defined `keys` nowhere.

Comment: `import`ing the `functions` module will not automatically execute the `dictionary()` function defined inside of it, and even if it did there would be a `NameError: name 'keys' is not defined`.

Comment: Forget what i've written. What i want to do is; There will be 2 files `file1.py` and `file2.py` . `file1.py` contains my class and function definition and `file2.py` will call the function that will fill the dictionary. So that, i want to define a global empty dictionary on `file1.py` then in `file2.py` i will call the `function` several times which will form the `dictionary` after that i will print the `dictionary` outside of the `function`.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish. But to be able to use another python function from another file, you'll want to something like this:

The file names file1.py and file2.py so that is why in my import statement I reference file1.

File1.py

```
class functions:
    my_dict = {}
    keys_list = []
    def dictionary(self):
        for i in range(3):
            self.my_dict.__setitem__(str(i),i)
            self.keys_list.append(str(i))
```

file2.py

```
from file1 import functions
tmp = functions()
tmp.dictionary()
print("Keys: " + str(tmp.keys_list))
print("Dictionary: " + str(tmp.my_dict))
```

Alternative solution global keywords:

File1.py

```
def dictionary():
    global my_dict 
    my_dict= {}
    global keys_list 
    keys_list = []
    for i in range(3):
        my_dict.__setitem__(str(i),i)
        keys_list.append(str(i))
```

file2.py

```
import tmp1

tmp1.dictionary()

print("Keys:" + str(tmp1.keys_list))
print("Dictionary: " + str(tmp1.my_dict))
```

Output:
[image]

Hope this helps (I can elaborate if you'd like as well)!

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking (or answering) a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Why not. I don’t see the issue

Comment: Did you read the reasons mentioned in the link? Primarily because it prevents others from being able to copy and paste it.

Comment: @anonymousCoder at least from my country we cannot access any image on stackoverflow.

Comment: Forget what i've written. What i want to do is; There will be 2 files `file1.py` and `file2.py` . `file1.py` contains my class and function definition and `file2.py` will call the function that will fill the dictionary. So that, i want to define a global empty dictionary on `file1.py` then in `file2.py` i will call the `function` several times which will form the `dictionary` after that i will print the `dictionary` outside of the `function`. @anonymousCoder I hope i could've explained the story.

Comment: @python101 Alright I have two examples above that access some scoped varibles in file1.py. The first one uses class scoping and the other *I think* scopes it to the file globally.